# Use proxy in iOS to to use Apps outside the U.S

Tags: ios, proxy, hulu, paypal

I live outside the US and would like to use some Apps that only work in US territory.

Example: Square (to accept credit card payments), Paypal mobile, Hulu, etc...

**Is there a way to make iOS believe that it´s in the US?**

Answer (score 1):

In order to access geoblocked websites you need to have a VPN application enabled to re-route your traffic through a US IP address.

For iOS the best solution I have found is [hotspotshield](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hotspot-shield-vpn/id443369807?mt=8).
It does have a subscription fee for using but it seems to work well so far.

It is also available as an OSX application for the desktop.

Comment: You should also mention, that it's ad-supported.

Answer (score 1):

For apps, a proxy is not the solution. I myself am using a VPN service. I have heard of free ones, but i find the paid ones more reliable, speedy, and user friendly. Most of these services have a guide for setting up the VPN settings on the iOS device. VPN is set up in `Settings -> General -> Network -> VPN`.

When using a VPN solution, all internet traffic on the iOS device will be goning through the chosen IP adress (for you, this should be one from the US).

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using HideMyAss VPN service for a few months and it is great. It is also a paid subscription but uses Tunnelblick client which is light and I just keep it connected at all times and have no performance issues either. You can select your VPN server also and they have servers available all over the world.
It's not only great for accessing geoblocked websites but great for just privacy in general.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a VPN, either on the iOS device directly (it has this option in the Network settings), or on your Mac (and then share the VPN via WiFI Internet Sharing).

I use [AceVPN](http://www.acevpn.com/). They also have a UK endpoint, so that you can watch BBC.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of hidemyass! It is well documented they cooperate with law enforcement. If you are going to use a privacy service, choose one thats been around for 15+ years, before being anonymosu was cool. Only two services come to mind. Ultimate-Anonymity.com and Cotse.net

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at using the personalVPN Pro service from Witopia.net. Their service is excellent and you could use the VPN to tunnel traffic through a U.S. based server. Check out their services here: https://www.witopia.net/products/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always preferred to host my own smart DNS/proxy and selectively forward DNS requests for sites like Hulu, Netflix, etc. to it. Traditional VPNs (if you respect the terminology) are not the right solution for streaming video since they essentially proxy everything by routing all traffic to your VPN server.

Ideally, you want to proxy only the web/application traffic via another location and leave the video/audio traffic to  be delivered to you from the closest CDN PoP, which certainly won't be the case if you try to access the likes of akamai.com from the UK via your US server.

Anyway, I've spent some time recently trying to get Hulu Plus going in the UK, but this should work on any geo-blocked site in theory.

In case anyone is interested the full write-up is here:
http://anton.belodedenko.me/watch-hulu-plus-outside-of-the-us/

Good luck!

-- ab1